# Download images from server at time interval

Tags: javascript, url, download

I'm trying to create a program that downloads the images from a site at regular intervals from url that have this form https://loremipsum.com/**********.png. Where the ten asterisks are the possible characters of the image url on the site server and are a combination of lowercase, uppercase letters and numbers, so (26 + 26 + 10) ^ 10 possible combinations (therefore 839.299.365.868.340.224 combinations). I would also like to do that when the server gives me an "access denied" response it goes on and so on. How could I do ? Could my computer hold up?

Comment: If we assume that each image will take 50ms to query (send the request & get a positive or negative response), it will take ~10 billion years. Could the Earth hold up?

Comment: I calculated the combination for 72^10, now I corrected for 62^10